# protractor is using old webdriver version while latest is installed in system

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver-manager

I'm working with protractor to run end-2-end test for my app. When I try to run the app, I get following error

```
[16:17:53] E/local - Error code: 135
[16:17:53] E/local - Error message: Could not find chromedriver at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.26
[16:17:53] E/local - Error: Could not find chromedriver at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.26
```

I don't know why its looking for version 2.26 while when I run command

```
webdriver-manager --version
```

it gives me version 2.32. I've also updated it (locally and globally) again by running

```
webdriver-manager update -g --versions.chrome=2.32
```

but it doesn't seems to work. I've also checked manually that webdriver exe with version 2.32 is available at the location being referred in error i.e. C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.26 .

Also, when I try to update webdriver-manager with following command, I place webdriver-manager exe with version 2.26 in the mentioned location. I don't know whether it is reading it from some config or from somewhere else because I'm unable to locate it. Need help in how to get rid of this 2.26 version and how to get protractor work with latest version (i.e. 2.32).

Comment: run `webdriver-manager clean`, then update again

Comment: I've tried this but result is same.

Comment: After you ran `webdriver-manager clean`, did the \chromedriver_2.26 directory get removed? If not, manually delete it and retry the install. Also, verify in your `package.json` that there are no dependency on a specific version of chrome

Comment: yes, When I do webdriver-manager clean, the chromedriver_2.26 get removed but when I do webdriver-manager update, it again downloads chromedriver_2.26 through curl. I relly want to know where this curl command is written and why its ALWAYS download 2.26 version and not the latest. Even I tried to update it with --versions.chrome=2.32 flag as well but result is same.

Comment: which version of protractor are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to fix this issue through **webdriver-manager update** or **npm install/update** but found a workaround for it. I've manually downloaded the chromedriver version **2.32**. Renamed the **.exe** file to **chromedriver_2.26.exe** and then replaced it on **C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.26** and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the ChromeDriver versions used by Protractor's webdriver-manager are always too far behind for my needs.

The solution I found for this is:

1. Download the [Selenium Server Standalone](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)
2. Download the [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) version you want.
3. You will then create a **.bat** file with the following:

   java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\path_to_your_files\chromedriver -jar C:\path_to_your_files\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -port 4444

Then you can just double-click on the **.bat** file and start your Selenium server with any ChromeDriver version you want. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks GoLGo13 for your response, but I didn't work out for me as Protractor try to start chromedriver and selenium itself so it still taking the wrong versions. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when i upgraded ChromeDriver from 75 to 79. Even though "webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=79..." did place the latest exe under rootfolder\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium, Protractor was still picking the old version.

For me the issue got resolved when i manually placed the latest version of ChromeDriver under the rootfolder\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium and also updated the update-config.json located in the same folder.